xpub master pub key view only wallet shows different balance than seed generated wallet with same pub key? also different addresses
okay.  Here is what I've done:

generated a new electrum wallet "WEL" on 3/3/24.

In btcpay server imported a view only wallet using xpub key from WEL.   (apparently didn't manually verify addresses)

BTCpay View Only Wallet "WELBTC"   shows a balance.

Seed generated electrum wallet WEL shows zero balance.

If i use pub key from WEL to generate a view only wallet in sparrow or electrum.  Shows balance.  I have verified the xpub is the same in all scenarios.

If I import WEL seed into sparrow or electrum as a hot wallet. Shows no balance.
If I import into sparrow via wallet.dat file.  Shows no balance.

WEL and WELBTC show different addresses and different address formats. (WEL shows 1xlk0u2343.  simple(older style addresses)

WELBTC(view only) shows newer bc1 style addresses.


The seed and xpub are from the same wallet in all scenarios.   Where is the btc and how do I spend it?!
EDIT:  resolved it myself.   Just in case anyone else ever has a similar issue,
I used the "getmasterprivate() command int he electrum console.  and created a new wallet/imported this master priv key into sparrow.   the masterpriv key showed all balances across different address formats.

Hi Dave, could you post the part that you added in the edit as an answer instead? We encourage self-answers when people figure out their own issue as they may help others
